# New line and returns ignored in setMessageBody

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Am I doing something dumb? I can pre-fill and email ok but the "\r\n" is ignored in the emailBody:

```
- (void) sendEventInEmail
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    NSString *emailSubject = [eventDictionary objectForKey:EVENT_NAME_KEY];

    [picker setSubject:emailSubject];

    // Fill out the email body text
    NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/whats-on-reading/id347859140?mt=8"; // Link to iTune App link
    NSString *content = [eventDictionary objectForKey:@"Description"];
    NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\nSent using <a href = '%@'>What's On Reading</a> for the iPhone.", content, iTunesLink];

    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Regards

Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doh... been working too hard and mixing Objective C strings with HTML.  Used `<p>` and `</p>` tags to fix.

Dave

Comment: I had HTML set to YES, switched to no and new lines worked. What is "and formatting codes"?

Comment: @quantumpotato : Yours is the only solution that worked

Answer (score 28):

If isHTML set YES \n does not work you either have to set isHTML:NO or use a HTML line break  such as **`<br />`** to enter a **new line**.

**`<p> </p>`** inserts a new **paragraph** which usually means double line break.

Try this with isHTML:YES:

```
[picker setMessageBody:@"1st line<br />2nd line<br />3rd line<br />and so on..." isHTML:YES];
```

If isHTML:NO just put \n

```
[picker setMessageBody:@"1st line\n2nd line\n3rd line\nand so on..." isHTML:NO];
```

It will give you this:

1st line
2nd line
3rd line
and so on...