# Spacing in string variable

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I would like to have spacing in my `setMessageBody`

```
mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Text Text2", isHTML: false)
```

**The output I get**

> Text Text2

**Expected Output:**

> Text
>
> Text2

any ideas?

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: hmm, dont know why it didnt show Text2 in the next line.. want Text2 in the next line

Comment: Did you try `"Text<br />Text2"`?

Comment: thanks Rakesha for edit :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New line and returns ignored in setMessageBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554250/new-line-and-returns-ignored-in-setmessagebody)

Comment: Maybe `"Text \n Text2"` ?

Comment: As `isHtml` is  set to false, it is in fact `"Text\nText2"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Text Text2", isHTML: false)
```

With `isHTML` set to false, use `"Text\nText2"`.

With `isHTML` set to true, use `"Text<br />Text2"`.

Answer (score 1):

`mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Hello World \nThis is a new line", isHTML: false)`

try This one

use \n for new line

Check Below Image [image]